# Unit testing class instance getting null

Tags: android, android-testing

i am just doing unit test for my class named Card

```
public class Card{
private KeyStore kestore;
private Cipher cipher;

public Card(){
}

public void generateRandom(){
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");

        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
}

public void init(){
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);

        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
}
}
```

and the below is my unit testing coding.

```
    public class cardTest extends AndroidTestCase{
    Card card;

        @Override
        protected void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            card = new Card();
        }

        @Override
        protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
            super.tearDown();
        }

        public class testgenerateRandom(){
            card.generateRandom();
        }

        public class testinit(){
            card.init();
        }
    }
```

so in the above unit test,

the testinit() will call the init of the Card class. there keystore becomes null. i already initialized the keystore in generateRandom() which is the first test case.

whenever the first test case (testgenerateRandom()) done, the card instance becomes null. so that keystore also becomes null

why is the card instance becomes null? can any help me in that?

Comment: Please post your real code or at least something that actually compiles.

Comment: Updated it can you see it... @m0skit0

Comment: @downvoter Can i get the reason for down voting?

Comment: Still not valid code. I think the downvoting reason is pretty clear: not valid code, horrible formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that JUnit will create a new instance of your `cardTest` class for each test method it runs, meaning `testgenerateRandom()` won't be called before `testinit()` as you probably expect, and both methods will use different instances of `Card`. Make sure to configure the instance under test properly in `setUp()` for each test method.

Comment: Can we able to restrict the second call of setup() method?

Comment: @Vji That's not how JUnit works. If you don't want it to be called in some tests, then you need to include it only on the tests you want it called. Note that JUnit tests are meant to be totally independent from each other.